# After a login has been created from an asymmetric key and some permissions are assigned, how do I enumerate the permissions

Tags: sql-server

Using MS Sql Server, I want to check the permissions of a login that was created from an asymmetric key.

The usual way to get permissions for a login is by impersonating and using
fn_my_permissions.

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'JupiterLogin';  
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(null, 'DATABASE')   
REVERT;
```

I get this error:

> Msg 15517, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal
>   "JupiterLogin" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be
>   impersonated, or you do not have permission.

Comment: You say "login" but then use `EXECUTE AS USER`. A `LOGIN` and a `USER` are the not the same object type; one is a server object the other a database object. Correct terminology is important. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logins created from certificates or asymmetric keys are used for code signing purposes. Usually, it means with SQLCLR routines.

They cannot be used to connect to SQL Server. 
And they cannot impersonated. So the following snippet will not work.

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'JupiterLogin';
```

To lists the permissions explicitly granted or denied to server principals use the following snippet.

```
SELECT pr.principal_id, pr.name, pr.type_desc,   
    pe.state_desc, pe.permission_name   
FROM sys.server_principals AS pr   
JOIN sys.server_permissions AS pe   
    ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id
WHERE NAME = 'JupiterLogin'
```

Comment: You can [create database users from certificates and asymmetric keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) even though the principals cannot authenticate. I commonly use this method to sign T-SQL modules with a certificate based on a user with additional permissions.

Comment: Correct Dan. Fixed in the answer. But still cannot connect to SQL Server.

Comment: The login is created for the assembly so code in the assembly can access the file system. I do this:GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO AssemblyNameLogin;  Then later I want to check if this permission has been assigned.

Comment: IMO you can execute just this SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('JupiterLogin', 'DATABASE') without EXECUTE AS USER = 'JupiterLogin';   ( that cause the error )

Comment: When I do that I don't see anything that tells me the login has external_access.

Comment: Such a user, created by a certificate or an asymmetric key, cannot be impersonated. sys.fn_my_permissions returns a list of the permissions effectively granted to the caller.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I need a script that can tell me if the login has been granted external_access as in the statement above.

Comment: To lists the permissions explicitly granted or denied to server principals use the snippet in the answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry for being dense this morning. That is what I need. I thank you so much for your kindness and help!